# How do stocks like INL (traded in Frankfurt) work?

Tags: stocks, trading, europe, nasdaq

Intel is traded under [INTC](https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AINTC&ei=l6HIWcCfNJXfsAG09YmgBg) in NASDAQ. Intel is traded under [INL](https://finance.google.com/finance?q=FRA%3AINL&ei=c6HIWZjgB8SHsAGw56iYBA) in Frankfurt.

What makes this possible? I assume these are the same company and somehow track each other but given the exchanges have different opening times, what processes makes it possible for this to work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**A "stock price" is nothing but the price at which some shares of that stock were sold on an exchange from someone willing to sell those shares at that price (or more) to someone willing to buy them at that price (or less).**

Pretty much every question about how stock prices work is answered by the paragraph above, which an astonishingly large number of people don't seem to be aware of.

So there is no explicit "tracking" mechanism at all. Just people buying and selling, and if the current going price on two exchanges differ, then that is an opportunity for someone to make money by buying on one exchange and selling on the other - until the prices are close enough that the fees and overhead make that activity unprofitable. This is called "arbitrage" and a common activity of investment banks or (more recently) hedge funds and specialized trading firms spun off by said banks due to regulation.

Comment: IOW: the "tracking" mechanism is called "market".

Comment: But how is it determined that someone actually has Intel shares in the first place on a new exchange? Did Intel decide to be traded on both exchanges and provide a select amount of shares to each or did someone manually move them and have someone delist the shares on one exchange and list them on another?

Comment: @Coburn I would guess that they were independent public offerings.

Comment: @Coburn: Listing and delisting is something that an exchange does to a stock as a whole, not individual shares. And listing typically requires significant effort from the company, at least for the bigger exchanges. So yes, Intel decided they wanted to be listed on both exchanges. But of course they did not provide shares to be traded, the owners of those shares do.

Comment: @Coburn: as for how is it determined that someone actually has Intel shares in the first place, ultimately that is determined by a central registry of shares, which is managed either by the company (i.e. Intel) or a separate securities depository organization like Euroclear or DTC. However, orders on a stock exchange have to be placed through a brokerage, and whether and how shares can be transferred between exchanges depends on the brokerage, which would need to be licensed at both exchanges or cooperate with other brokerages, and may demand a fee for this.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "... at that price (or less) to ... that price (or more)" rather than the other way around?

Comment: @user20574: no. The seller would gladly take a higher price and the buyer a lower one. The exchange determines at which point in the overlap the trade happens, usually by considering all orders active at the same time.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Oh I see now, it can be interpreted either way. I took it as "that price (or more) is the price the seller specified" which is incorrect; you intended "that price (or more) is the price at which the seller will allow a transaction to take place".

Comment: @Coburn Generally, yes, a large company may "apply for their shares to be listed" at multiple exchanges, basically to make it easier for people in those countries to trade in them. In theory, you can (within reason, and possibly subject to local laws) choose to trade on any exchange, although for most people it will be more expensive and involve bigger hoops to jump through to trade on a foreign one (see [Company stock listed in multiple exchanges?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/77103/35567)).

Answer (score 5):

They don't have to track each other, it could just be listed on more than one exchange.

The price on one exchange does not have to match or track the price on the other exchange.

This is actually quite common, as many companies are listed on two or more exchanges around the world.